# Is there a rule on which order to write derived SI units?

Tags: units, si-units

I noticed from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit that derived units have to be written in a specific order. For example Newton Metre is written:

$$\text{m}^2⋅\text{kg}⋅\text{s}^{−2}$$

But not:

$$\text{s}^{−2}⋅\text{kg}\cdot\text{m}^2$$

I may assume that the 22 + 6 SI units have a weight order such as

$$ \text{m} > \text{kg} > \text{s} $$

Is this really the case, or are there any exceptions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Quantities#Dimensions_of_derived_quantities

Comment: I've never noted any required ordering in my career, though it is usual to put denominators last.

Comment: @Jasper, Well, I am blind then :(

Comment: People normally write the units of work as $\text{N}\cdot\text{m}$ rather than $\text{m}\cdot\text{N}$. I've always assumed this was to keep it from looking like millinewtons. Cf. foot-pounds.

Comment: @BenCrowell, this is well seen.

Comment: For your interest, the SI units are usually referred as MKS systems (i.e. metre-kilogram-second); whereas Gaussian units as CGS systems (i.e. centimetre-gram-second).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an official definition that says the order is always m, kg, s, A, K, mol, cd with the appropriate exponents when only base units are used.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Quantities#Dimensions_of_derived_quantities

I think that derived units can be used more freely.

Also this does not seem to be too stricty used because 1C is usually 1As and not 1sA.

Other possible orderings include alphabetical or by decreasing exponent.

One can also try to use the less confusing notation: if m can be understood as both milli and meter, it might be better to put the other unit first so m is not the prefix.

Comment: Whooh, that's interesting. I have always written $\text{A}\cdot\text{s}$ instead of $\text{s}\cdot\text{A}$ :)

Comment: What is your source for stating that *there seems to be an official defintion...* ? The wiki article does not refer to any convention about order or writing combinations of units.

Comment: You use either a thin space or a centered dot to separate units where there is the possibility of confusing the leading abbreviation with a SI prefix. But I'll note that in many cases the common usage is historical (like $1\,\mathrm{N} = 1\,\mathrm{kg\cdot m/s^2}$ rather than $1 \,\mathrm{m \, kg \, s^{-2}}$.

Comment: https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:80000:-1:ed-1:v1:en is wiki's source for the Order of dimensions, section 3.7

Comment: I cannot find any reference to order in s 3.7 of the ISO document. A consistent order is used for listing the 7 base units, but nothing is said about using this order for derived units. In fact, some examples have base units in a different order, eg $ML^{-3}$ and $TL^{-\frac12}$.